# Can I show the pre-processor output IntelliSense generates?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, c-preprocessor, intellisense

In VisualStudio 2013, the `/P` flag makes the pre-processor of VC++ output to a file.

Does such a flag exist for the IntelliSense compiler, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this wasn't made accessible. What would it produce? The Intellisense compiler and the VC++ compiler are sufficiently identical that the output of preprocessing is generally identical. And past that phase, you're no longer talking about readable C++ code anymore - it's internal representations.

Comment: "generally" is the key here. I have some macro meta programming code that uses Boost.PP and compiles fine under VC++ but is not interpreted correctly by IntelliSense and I would like to see what the problem is. Also, shouldn't this answer be a comment?

Comment: @iFreilicht: Made the actual answer explicit. Boost PP is indeed stretching the limits of the preprocessor. That also means `/P` may not actually show you the real problem. Its output is flat text, while the output of the preprocessor formally is a token stream. Subtle difference, but it's that kind of difference which you see across different preprocessors.

Comment: The thing is, `/P` has no problems to show. VC++ compiles the code fine, but IntelliSense just doesn't extend some macros for whatever reason, underling lines of code that don't have any actual problem.

Comment: That's yet another problem: any compiler finds issues in the expanded sources; mapping those back to the original location in the source code is hard.